# How to use Doxygen plugin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, doxygen, documentation-generation

I need to create a document for my app in Android Studio. I have already created document using Doxygen in eclipse but I don't know how to use Doxygen in Android Studio to generate automatic documentation. I tried searching the web but all I could find is Eclipse Doxygen plugin, can anyone a way to use Doxygen in android studio?

Comment: Hai Vicky... Did you got any Input?

Comment: @Muhamed Sry man, i didn't find any soluton.

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio 2.0:
`Tools` -> `Generate JavaDoc...`

setting Output directory:
[image]

output like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Tools -> Generate JavaDoc` seems to be the way to go.